# Web Api capture request data from Adobe Acrobat form submit

Tags: itext, asp.net-web-api2, adobe, acrobat

I have a PDF which has a submit button which will submit the PDF fields as an html form to my web API. The submit part works, however it is sending the request payload in a format I have never seen before
[image: Request payload]

Also the request doesn't show the content-type being sent. I supposed it was being sent as application/octet-stream so I added [this](https://gist.github.com/aliostad/2519771) custom `MediaTypeFormatter` I found and it still didn't work.

I am filling the PDF fields using iTextSharp and the sending it to the client. The client creates a BLOB URL to display it in an `iframe`. I noticed that the problem is due to this, because when opening the PDF by itself and filling the data manually and then submitting it works fine, so the problem has to be either when I fill the form fields or when I create the BLOB URL in the client.

Answer (score 3):

That's an Adobe format called FDF (Forms Data Format) but that's just one option for the submit format. You can also submit the data as the equivalent of an HTML GET using the settings shown in the images below.

[image]

If your API can accept data from HTML forms, it should work from Acrobat as well.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, yes that is how my setting look like right now, however it stills sends the request as a POST and in FDF format.

Comment: That makes no sense then. Check the properties of submit button again. It's also possible that the submission is triggered via JavaScript elsewhere and that the script is using the default setting rather than HTML. If you can share the PDF form, I can tell you for sure what's going on.

Comment: so this it seems to be working in IE, however it does not in Chrome, Firefox or Edge, any idea?

Comment: IE is loading the PDF using the Adobe Reader plugin. Chrome, Firefox, and Edge use their own built-in PDF viewer that doesn't support forms in quite the same way. I suggest you set the URL to be absolute if it's not already and force download the PDF rather than have it open in the browser. If that's not possible, you'll need to rethink your approach since you can't get consistent behavior out of the browser-based PDF viewers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, yes i am going to look for another approach, like submitting via javascript.